# Dynamic set of beans chain execution in chain or responsibility

Tags: java

I am working on implementing chain of responsibility for execution of certain action. From the high level there are services and in each service there are chain of actions that gets executed. Currently I have set of action beans that execute when Service I was wondering if there is any way I can utilize map to achieve this and still do auto injection.

Answer (score 0):

If the Product is set once in your application lifecycle you can use spring profiles. Create separate profiles for Product 1 and Product 2 and annotate your Service class with @Profile annotation. In this case you can fill your actions list with different values for each profiles.

If Product can be changed dynamically in runtime, you can declare your Product beans by implementing InitializngBean and BeanNameAware interfaces.
BeanNameAware let you check whether the configuration is for Product 1 or Product 2, whereas InitializingBean give you a chance to setup your lists in different ways according to the bean name.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Annotating with @Profile for service for different product will not work in this case as service definitions are a static flow in spring integration but the action beans chain under it needs to be dynamically determined based on product. I will look into the second option you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to implement flexibility where action beans 1,2,3 gets
>   added to chain for ServiceA execution if it is product 1 but only
>   action beans 1,3 gets added to chain for ServiceA execution if it is
>   product 2?

The main issue with this approach is that the autowiring happens when the application starts, not when `execute` is called on the service.  If you need to process both types at runtime, you need to autowire all of the actions.

What you could do to avoid brittle if/else in the service class is to move the responsibility for deciding which actions apply to a product into the action itself.

Something like this:

```
    public enum ProductType {
    PROD1, PROD2
}

public interface Product {
    public ProductType getType();
}

public interface Action {
    public boolean execute(Product p);
    public ProductType[] supportedTypes();
}

@Component
@Order(1)
public class Action1 implements Action {
    public boolean execute(Product p) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public ProductType[] supportedTypes() {
        return ProductType.values();
    }
}

@Component
@Order(2)
public class Action2 implements Action {
    public boolean execute(Product p) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public ProductType[] supportedTypes() {
        return new ProductType[] {PROD2};
    }
}

@Service
public class ServiceA {

    private Map<ProductType, List<Action>> actionMap = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public boolean execute(Product product) {
        List<Action> actions = actionMap.get(product.getType());
        // call each action
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setActions(List<Action> actions) {

        for (Action action : actions) {
            for (ProductType type : action.supportedTypes()) {
                if (!actionMap.containsKey(type)) {
                    actionMap.put(type, new ArrayList<>());
                }
                actionMap.get(type).add(action);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked your suggestion! Above, combined with Qualifier usage helps me do what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting a lot from Autowiring. In situations like this I would supplement the Autowiring, which is really a case of following the static configuration within the code's annotations, with a configuration file. Use a spring beans xml file to put the custom chain together for a specific context. The good thing is that everything you don't wire up within the XML file can be Autowired from the annotations. Spring is very good at letting you mix metaphors.